# assigning value to shared_ptr <IplImage>

Tags: boost

i am using obj C and i am having problem with assigning const IplImage* to the shared_ptr

i have defined a type as below

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<const IplImage> SharedImage;
```

and then i create an instance of it assign the instance to `const IplImage* image`.

how do i do that?

i understand that i have to initialize the IplImage that my shared_ptr is pointing to. so i have tried something like this, no error but unsure how to assign the variable image to it.

```
SharedImage shared_image(new const IplImage(*cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)));
```

i tried `shared_image.get() = image;`

but it gives me error. any suggestion please? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset)

```
shared_image.reset(image);
```

This interface would also allow you to set the corresponding deleter (if not the default). This capability would not exist with any of the approaches you were looking for